# Prove that $a^b b^c c^a \geq a^c b^a c^b$

Tags: inequality

I want to prove that 
$$a^b b^c c^a \geq a^c b^a c^b$$

a, b, c are integers and $0 <a\leq b\leq c$

I have tried using Muirhead's Inequality, but didn't work.

Any hints please?

Comment: are there any conditions on $a,b,c$?

Comment: I just edited it! This is everything given in the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way, as $f(x) = \log x$ is concave, we have for the three points $a, b, c$, the slope of the consecutive secants to be decreasing.  i.e. 
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \ge \frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}$$
$$\iff (c-b) f(a) + (b-a)f(c) \le (c-a)f(b)$$
which is equivalent to your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality holds for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<a\leq b\leq c$, not just for integral values of $a,b,c$.  Muirhead's Inequality shouldn't be a good way to solve this problem, because the inequality is not symmetric.  Somebody posted a solution with the Rearrangement Inequality, which should work if you treat it correctly, although I have no idea why the solution was deleted.  Or you can just do it with the Weighted AM-GM Inequality as shown below:

> $$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\frac{c-b}{c-a}}\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^{\frac{b-a}{c-a}}\leq \frac{c-b}{c-a}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+\frac{b-a}{c-a}\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)=1\,.$$

Comment: Notice that my solution was wrong. They aren't exactly in the opposite order.

Comment: But rearrangement should definitely work.  So, maybe you can edit your answer and repost it.

Comment: I am planning to, but this would take some time, as I am not planning to use this site for quite some from now.

Comment: @MXYMXY: Actually, I first proved it in a similar way, justifying it by using the rearrangement inequality and the greedy algorithm, but one of my friends told me that the solution was not mathematical and didn't accept it as an answer

Comment: $b^{c-a} \ge a^{c-a}$, but – unless I am mistaken – $c^{a-b} \le a^{a-b}$.

Comment: I made my own mistake.  Edited now.